# Can a library be used to force all copies of a spreadsheet to reference the most current version of a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, libraries

I've created a Google Sheets spreadsheet template with a script that my users can access via a menu option.  This "template" is new and undergoes frequent enhancements and bug fixes.

I'd like to find a way to ensure that all copies that are made of the template access the most recent version of the script.

I read this:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#testAndDebug

...but the first warning at the top of the page says not to use libraries for long-running scripts. Mine takes 3 - 30 minutes to run, depending upon the amount of input data.

If I do use a library, do I have to put it in development mode in order for copies of the template to reference the latest version of the script?

Sorry.  I hope this is making sense.  I'd appreciate any advice you might have.

Comment: The way I understand the documentation, is that your users of the library would need to have edit access to your library project to automatically be using the latest version.  The setting for development mode is made by the user, not the owner of the library.  So the *user* needs to turn the development mode button to ON.  If you encourage your users to put the library into development mode, and you give them edit access, then they will be using the latest version.  But I would have a development file that is separate.  Add-ons can be published "unlisted" and update automatically.

Comment: Thanks, Sandy.  I think for now I might just continue to push the users to grab a new copy of the template each time they need to run the script.  It really should just be needed once per data set unless something goes wrong.

Comment: There is a new feature in Apps Script for providing your own manifest file.  I'm not sure if updating the manifest file can update the library version being used, but I did just see something about this.  If I get some information, hopefully I'll remember to post it.  You could post your question to the Apps Script Community  [Link to Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: Here is a link to a shared Apps Script file with some code examples on how to update the manifest file:  [Link to Apps Script file](https://script.google.com/d/1Tsq8dhMImTN8GWoTHB9DpnJG22x1Af52Jzpj2XoNppmOAJOUZy3gjtwu/edit)

Comment: It looks like there is a way to programmatically update the library version, but the problem is, that the user would need to enable Advanced Drive Service in order to get the internal manifest file from the Apps Script file.

Comment: Enabling Advanced Drive Service once, might be preferable to copying the template file every time.  But, it depends.  People might actually have less trouble copying the file than going into the script editor, then going into the developer console.  Everything has it's pros and cons.

Comment: Thanks, Sandy.  I'll look into it and ask a couple of users what makes the most sense to them.